# How to make one div always be at the bottom of the view and make top div resize based on bottom div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to web development and I'm working on something which requires two divs to always take up 100% of the viewport.

I have div A which is an interactive image that should be as big as possible and should take up the top part of the screen.

Then div B which contains either 1 or 2 buttons depending on what action is done on the interactive div A. Div B is at the bottom of the view.

Is there a clean way to make the size of A depend on the size that div B takes up dynamically? Like just the "remainder" of the viewport should be div A. I put an image below of what I'm attempting to achieve. The second image shows what would happen if some action is done in div A - for simplicity, we could say if some method potato() is called, we want div B to now contain two buttons.

[image]
I have tried doing a solution with:

```
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
```

and Div B looks 90% right that way, but it doesn't resize Div A and I also  don't want Div B "covering" anything in this way. I just want it to be the same level as Div A and sharing the space to get 100% of the viewport.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'd prefer to use plain CSS if possible. I'm doing some away team work and can't add much in the way of libraries or new dependencies to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kt931frp/1/ the trick is using flex as suggested by the below answer.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="part1"></div>
<div class="part2">
<div contenteditable="true"class="contenteditable">continue typing...</div>
</div>
</div>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.part1 {
  background:#ffff00;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.part2 {
  padding: 2em;
  color: white;
  background:#ff0000;
}
.contenteditable{
  width:100%;
  min-height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is pretty easy using **Flexbox** and the [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property.
You can change the `padding` value to see how the top block reacts.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top-part {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* This tells `top-part` to take the remaining place. */
  background: violet;
}

.bottom-part {
  padding: 2em;
  color: white;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="top-part"></section>
  <section class="bottom-part">
    Some text here
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bringing my 2 cents, you can also take advantage of `display: table|table-row|table-cell` to create this layout (see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) on display property to know more).

The trick when using these properties, unless `display: flex`, is to tell the "actions" cell to measure 0.1px, which will force the cell to be the minimum possible. However, it does not crushes its inner content, allowing to dynamically adjust depending the content inside.

As cells are by default sharing spaces, this does the job for this kind of layout because the "Div A" is using the rest of the available space.

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ab10e29/) or use the snippet code below to play with it. I annoted the properties you can tweak.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.app {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: table;
}

.main,
.actions {
  display: table-row;
}

.main > div,
.actions > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 10px; /* tweak this */
  border-style: solid; /* tweak this */
}

.main > div {
  border-color: purple; /* tweak this */
  background-color: violet; /* tweak this */
}

.actions > div {
  padding: 20px; /* tweak this */
  border-color: blue; /* tweak this */
  background-color: lightblue; /* tweak this */
  height: 0.1px;
}

.button {
  width: 200px; /* tweak this */
  padding: 10px; /* tweak this */
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <main class="main">
    <div>
      Div A
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="actions">
    <div>
      <div>
        Div B - some text and 2 buttons
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">
          Button 1
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">
          Button 2
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Hope it help you getting inspiration.