# Using flexbox with absolute position children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am learning the ropes in CSS and I'm having issues with using flexbox in conjunction with absolute children and an overlapping div. Based on questions online, I see that there may be an issue with it, I just don't see a way to fix what I'm running into.

I asked a question previously and the solution works fine: [How to make one div always be at the bottom of the view and make top div resize based on bottom div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588055/how-to-make-one-div-always-be-at-the-bottom-of-the-view-and-make-top-div-resize/56588452#56588452)

It was basically for the top div (Div A) to fill the remaining space of the view port that the bottom div wasn't filling up dynamically.

[image]

However, I'm running into a problem because my divA contains children elements which need to overlap and are using position: absolute.

Prior to dealing with flex, this is how I defined my top div: (please excuse naming and stuff. I made them dummy names for the sake of this example.)

```
    #divA {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 70vh;
        position: relative;
    }

    #innerContainer {
        position: absolute;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
    }

    #centeredIcon {
        width: 2em;
        height: 3em;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

And the elements were like:

```
    <div id="divA">
        <div id="innerContainer"/>
        <img id="centeredIcon" src="..."/>
    </div>
    <div id="divB"> ... </div>
```

Upon trying to convert the outer container for Div A to use `flex: 1 0 auto;` and put divA and divB in a wrapper div, my innerContainer of divA pretty much disappears (size of 0).

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: could you please move this example into a codepen to help others troubleshoot?

Comment: Here's a fiddle that has the overall components but I can't drop my code in here as-is so its a bit of a simplified version of what I had initially before trying to add "divB", the bottom div which affects what size "divA" the top div should be:

https://jsfiddle.net/dz76vre5/3/

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/bhe5jgdq/ (basically instead of *inherit* you can use 100% width and height... also you can just use `flex-grow: 1` to occupy remaining space and add `flex-shrink: 0` on the `divB` to avoid shrinking in some cases) if it looks fine, I'll add this as an answer

Comment: @kukkuz it seems like a working approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolutely positioned element `innerContainer` is not properly filling up the space of its container `divA` - instead of using `width: inherit` and `height: inherit` you can use 100% and also set`top` and `left` to zero.

Optionally I've added `flex-shrink: 0` on `divB` so that it doesn't shrink when the window height is small - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#divA {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1; /* occupy remaining space */
  background: lightblue;
}

#divB {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* do not shrink */
  background: lightgreen;
  /* center horizontally and place buttons vertically */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#innerContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#centeredIcon {
  width: 2em;
  height: 3em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="divA">
    <div id="innerContainer"></div>
    <img id="centeredIcon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
  </div>
  <div id="divB">
    <button>button 1</button>
    <button>button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```